# send 2 or more input with the same name with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how are you?

i have the nex code.

```
<input name='uno[]' value='gonzalo' />
<input name='uno[]' value='marcos'/>
<input name='uno[]' value='martin'/>
<input name='uno[]' value='claudio'/>
```

If y send the form to Ejample procesa.php I can take the variable in this way.

```
$variable=$_POST['uno'];
```

echo $variable[2]  // martin

But , how can i send the variable through ajax?

Anyone help?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 1):

Put your data into an array

```
var uno = [];
$('input[name="uno[]"]').each( function() {
    uno.push(this.value);
});
```

and send it

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "procesa.php",
  data: {uno: uno}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that manages all fields of a form.

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form action="procesa.php" id="myUno" method="post">
    <input name='uno[0]' value='gonzalo' /><br/>
    <input name='uno[1]' value='marcos'/><br/>
    <input name='uno[2]' value='martin'/><br/>
    <input name='uno[3]' value='claudio'/><br/>

    <select name="uno[4]" id="">
     <option value="">....</option>
      <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
      <option value="opt2" selected>opt2</option>
      <option value="opt3">opt3</option>
      <option value="opt4">opt4</option>
    </select><br/>

    <textarea name="uno[5]" id="" cols="30" rows="4">test content!!</textarea><br/>

    <label for="checkbox_1">checkbox 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="uno[6]" id="checkbox_1" value="checkbox_1" checked="checked"><br/>

    <label for="apple">Apple</label>
    <input type="radio" id="apple" name="uno[7]" value="apple">
    <label for="orange">Orange</label>
    <input type="radio" id="orange" name="uno[7]" value="orange" checked="checked">


    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="form_submit">
  </form>

  <div id="result"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="process.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**procesa.php**

```
<?php

$uno = $_POST['uno'];
var_dump($_POST);
```

**process.js**

```
$(function() {

  $( "#myUno" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();//

    //we get the data in a single table through our function below
    var formData = $('#myUno').serializeAssoc();
    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "procesa.php",
    data: { uno: formData.uno }
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $('#result').html(data); //displays the response returned. This is used to debug if necessary
    });

  });
});


$.fn.serializeAssoc = function() {
  var data = {};
  $.each( this.serializeArray(), function( key, obj ) {
    var a = obj.name.match(/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/);
    if(a !== null)
    {
      var subName = a[1];
      var subKey = a[2];
      if( !data[subName] ) data[subName] = [ ];
        if( data[subName][subKey] ) {
          if( $.isArray( data[subName][subKey] ) ) {
            data[subName][subKey].push( obj.value );
          } else {
            data[subName][subKey] = [ ];
            data[subName][subKey].push( obj.value );
          }
        } else {
          data[subName][subKey] = obj.value;
        }
      } else {
        if( data[obj.name] ) {
          if( $.isArray( data[obj.name] ) ) {
            data[obj.name].push( obj.value );
          } else {
            data[obj.name] = [ ];
            data[obj.name].push( obj.value );
          }
        } else {
          data[obj.name] = obj.value;
        }
      }
    });
    return data;
};
```

I found this plugin **$.fn.serializeAssoc** that works well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643310/jquery-serialize-form-data-to-associated-array)