# Ajax post multiple inputs

Tags: html, django, ajax

I have html input fields with the name personals. I use the [] such that I can have multiple inputs on the same name and post that.
Before I was using a normal submit form. And I got it in my Django backend with `getlist('personal[]')`
Everything worked as expected.

As information: the codes are not complete. Just the most important lines are shown.

My html code before

```
<input type="text" name="personals[]" id="personals[]" placeholder='Email'> 
<input type="text" name="personals[]" id="personals[]" placeholder='Phone'>
```

My view before

```
def build(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            personals = request.POST.getlist('personals[]')
```

Now I am using Ajax to submit it, without reloading the page.
It does not work anymore with `personals[]` therefore I have changed it too `personals` just without the parenthesis.

The problem is, that personal contains only the first input. But not all the others.

It is important to use the same input name (in this case `personals`) because I use some dynamic input fields, where the users can add more fields. Therefore I don't want to change the name to for example `personals1` and `personals2`.

My html code now

```
<input type="text" name="personals" id="personals" placeholder='Email'> 
<input type="text" name="personals" id="personals" placeholder='Phone'>
```

My view now

```
def build(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            personals = request.POST.get('personals')
```

My ajax function

```
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: "{% url 'creator:build' %}",
                data: {
                    name:$('#name').val(),
                    personals:$('#personals').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you have multiple values in 'personals' but you are only getting one in your view, you should try using `request.POST.getlist('personals[]')`.

As a more general point, you seem to be collecting email and phone data in your inputs - your input names should really be 'email' and 'phone' and you can use a Django form to render and process these inputs far more easily. If the user can create extra fields or forms then these can be handled by Django forms or formsets.

Comment: With `personal[]` I get an empty list. Because in ajax the variable is called only `personal`. I have the feeling I should change `val()` to something else to get Allvalues

Comment: Ah your JS code picks val() based on #personals which is an ID selector, it will only return one element

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
var personals = [];
$('input[name="personals[]"]').each(function() {
    personals.push(this.value);
});
```

Here the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: "{% url 'creator:build' %}",
            data: {
                name:$('#name').val(),
                personals: personals,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            })
```

and finally the view:

```
def build(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            personals = request.POST.getlist('personals[]')
```

[send 2 or more input with the same name with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823642/send-2-or-more-input-with-the-same-name-with-ajax)