# Form serializeArray get key:value if key is nested array in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form like this:

```
<select name="dog[0][name]">...</select>
<select name="dog[0][color]">...</select>
<select name="dog[0][height]">...</select>
<select name="dog[0][weight]">...</select>

<select name="dog[1][name]">...</select>
<select name="dog[1][color]">...</select>
<select name="dog[1][height]">...</select>
<select name="dog[1][weight]">...</select>
...
```

Now, if I call `$('form').serializeArray();` on this the output is like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "dog[0][name]",
        value: "ABC"
    },
    {
        name: "dog[0][color]",
        value: "Blue"
    },
    {
        name: "dog[0][height]",
        value: "41"
    },
    {
         name: "dog[0][weight]",
        value: "10"
    },
    {
        name: "dog[1][name]",
        value: "XYZ"
    },
    {
        name: "dog[1][color]",
        value: "Pink"
    },
    {
        name: "dog[1][height]",
        value: "27"
    },
    {
        name: "dog[1][weight]",
        value: "7"
    },
    // ...
]
```

How can I make this to be like:

```
{
    dog: [
        0: {"name": "ABC", "color": "Blue", "height": 41, "weight": "10"}
        1: {"name": "XYZ", "color": "Pink", "height": 27, "weight": "7"}
    ]
}
```

? Is there a way that won't require nested loops?

Comment: Answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643310/jquery-serialize-form-data-to-associated-array

Comment: There is a plugin for that if you don't want to build your own: https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Answer (score 1):

OK, I know my question is case-specific, but maybe this will help somebody as well. I came with my own simple (I think) solution (it's in coffeescript):

```coffee
values = $('form').serializeArray()

model = {}
for val in values
    matches = val.name.match /dog\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]/
    model[matches[1]] = {} if !model[matches[1]]
    model[matches[1]][matches[2]] = val.value
console.log model
```

Translated into pure JS it should be:

```js
var values = $('form').serializeArray();

var model = {};
for (var i = 0, var len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
    var val = values[i];
    var matches = val.name.match(/dog\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]/);
    if (!model[matches[1]]) {
        model[matches[1]] = {};
    }
    model[matches[1]][matches[2]] = val.value;
}
console.log(model);
```

Produces this output:

```
{
    0:
        {
            "name": "ABC",
            "color": "Blue",
            "height": "41",
            "weight": "10"
        }
    1:
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "color": "Pink",
            "height": "27",
            "weight": "7"
        }
}
```